# Testing for the absence of child records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two database tables with a one-to-many relationship. Is it possible to select records from the 'one' table for which no records exist in the 'many' table using a single SQL statement? If so, how?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [`OUTER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html):

```
select p.id
from parent p
left outer join child c on c.parent_id = p.id
where c.parent_id is null
```

Comment: @sreimer: You sure about that? See: [Left outer join vs NOT EXISTS](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/)

Comment: I've seen it make impressive improvements in my code. It will probably depend on how large your nested select result set is.

Comment: @sreimer: I think the key point for these queries is to use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN. NOT EXISTS should be better than both the LEFT JOIN and NOT IN.

Comment: Please note that my blog post on performance comparisons was for SQL Server and this question is for MySQL. The same performance characteristics may not apply to MySQL

Comment: Perfect, thank you. This is definitely the fastest query in my tests. Is there an optimum statement to select the opposite (i.e. parents WITH children)?

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
    from table1
    where not exists (select null 
                          from table2 
                          where MatchingColumn = Table1.MatchingColumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull all the records from the master table that do not have any children in the "many" table like so:

SELECT T.*
FROM Table1 T
WHERE T.Id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT FKID FROM Table2)

FKID is the Foreign Key ID that links back to the master table.